# R Tsp attribute coerces order comparison logicals into dates

Tags: r, statistics

A weird bug/feature that occurs when applying `stats::lag` to a date object and then using an order operation returns another date.

```
date1 <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
date2 <- as.Date("2016-12-31")
date1 < date2                 
#> [1] TRUE
date1 < lag(date2)            
#> [1] "1970-01-02"
```

As it turns out, `as.Date("1970-01-02") == structure(TRUE, class = "Date")`. Similarly, `date1 > lag(date2)` yields `as.Date("1970-01-01")`, which is `structure(FALSE, class = "Date")`. So the logical answer appears to be getting coerced into a date object.

Looking at the underlying objects, we have:

```
dput(date2)                   
#> structure(17166, class = "Date")
dput(lag(date2))              
#> structure(17166, class = "Date", .Tsp = c(0, 0, 1))
```

So it looks like the `.Tsp` argument to the `structure` is causing this issue.

From the [R documentation for `stats::tsp`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/tsp.html), the `tsp` attribute gives the start time *in time units*, the end time and the frequency of the object. Furthermore, from the [R documentation for `stats::lag`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lag.html), applying `lag` to an object automatically adds the `tsp` attribute to that object.

**Consequently, is it documented as a feature (and not a bug) that applying an order operation (e.g. `>` or `<`) to a date object with a `tsp` attribute returns the logical output coerced to a date?**

Comment: It's probably that `lag` is intended to be used on `ts()` objects, which are usually just plain numeric values.

Comment: @thelatemail I encountered this when I used `stats::lag` in `data.table`s, and didn't realise that `data.table::shift` is better.